# Azure Devops audit rest api continuation token using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am working on script which should output audit logs report in csv file for selected fields. Due to rest api result limitation I can not get all data at once.
If I pass continuation token manually I can get next set of data but I want script to generate all logs for given time frame

I tried this script which does not return all data -

```
$personalAccessToken = ""
$auth = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::                  
ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $auth")


do
{
$uri = "https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/audit/auditlog?      
startTime=2020-07-01T00.00.00&endTime=2020-10-   
15T16.00.00&continuationToken=$continuationToken&api-version=6.0-
preview.1"

$TestRuns = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get    
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty decoratedAuditLogEntries | 
Where-Object { $_.actionId -eq 'Git.RepositoryCreated' } |
Select-Object actorDisplayName, ProjectName, actionId, details, 
timestamp  
$continuationToken = $TestRuns.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'

$TestRuns
}
while ($continuationToken -ne $null)
```

I also tried with Invoke-webrequest it also does not provide all data. I have large chuck of logs.

How can I get all the data ?

Comment: Are you running this script from a pipeline? Then you could consider a *managed identity* to avoid replacing the authorization token.

Comment: no I am running this script on my local pc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure DevOps REST API call retrieving only top 100 records and ContinuationToken getting as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980722/azure-devops-rest-api-call-retrieving-only-top-100-records-and-continuationtoken)

Comment: @Matt I have updated answer above this is also not giving me all data after certain entry it stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution which worked for me -

```
$personalAccessToken = ""
$auth =  
[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes
(":$($personalAccessToken)"))

$headers = @{}
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $auth")

do
{
$uri =     
"https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/audit/auditlog?  
startTime=2020-09-20T20:42:20:3094806Z&endTime=2020-10-
15T20:42:20:3094806Z&continuationToken=$continuationToken&api-version=6.0-
preview.1"

$TestRuns = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Get 

$result = @( $TestRuns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty     
decoratedAuditLogEntries | 
Where-Object { $_.actionId -eq 'Git.RepositoryCreated' } |
Select-Object actorDisplayName, ProjectName, actionId, details, 
timestamp )

$continuationToken = $TestRuns.continuationToken 

$result | Export-Csv "/data.csv" -Append
}

while ($null -ne $continuationToken)
```