# Download audit logs in csv from azure DevOps UI using powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, azure-devops, azure-devops-analytics

Hi I am looking for a script which can download export logs in csv from azure DevOps using powershell for given time frame. like I can enter time frame and then script will download and return csv file from azure DevOps ui -

[image]

I found this script here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/615053/question-we-want-to-get-the-export-audit-log-using.html

I am not sure what username , password and url to use here

```
$Username = 'domain\user'
$Password = 'password'
$Url = "https://server:8080/tfs/_api/_licenses/Export"
$Path = "D:\temp\data.csv"
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object    
System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $url, $path )
```

I am not able to find any more data on this

Comment: Answer: _probably Yes_. Please show us the code you have already tried. Add info about what did not work as expected, possible error messages you may have received etc.

Comment: @Theo I updated code with only script I found for this and I am not sure about the value I need to put in the script . I also tried getting audit logs using rest api but its not proving all the Data here is question posted -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64392632/azure-devops-audit-rest-api-continuation-token-using-powershell?noredirect=1#comment113867920_64392632

Comment: Hi @megha, I have updated the API and add time frame, and now you can download export logs in csv from azure DevOps using powershell for given time frame. You can try it and kindly share the result here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @megha, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample you shared is download audit log form Azure DevOps Server, the url is `https://{your_server}/tfs/_api/_licenses/Export`, username , password are your username and password to log on to TFS.
Note: Do not forget add domain name before the username.

If you are using Azure DevOps Service, you can try this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/download%20log/download%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and power shell script to save the Audit log.

```
$outfile = "{Local path}"
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$AuditLogURL = "https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/audit/downloadlog?format=csv&startTime={startTime}&endTime={endTime}&api-version=6.1-preview.1" 
$AuditInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AuditLogURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get –OutFile $outfile
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer, Vito.  FYI, I answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64517722/574588